# Creating automatic objects in the Database (Django)

Tags: python, django

i am working on train booking system project and i want to access the seat number and location so i made a seats class that will help. the issue is that i want when the admin adds a new train **from the admin panel** the seats class automatically adds 100 seat into the DB because i don't think it makes any sense that the admin will add the 100 seat manually

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535389/django-creating-model-instances-newbie

Comment: Without knowing your full requirements, perhaps you'd be best to have a `seats_available` field in the `Train` class and set that to 100 initially. Create a `Seat` instance whenever you need to (customer purchases a seat etc.) and link it to the `Train` instance with a foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, there are multiple solutions to your problem:

1. You can listen to the [`post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#post-save).
2. You can overwrite the `save()` method on your `Train` model.
3. You can create a `ModelAdmin` subclass with a custom [`save_model()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model).

If you want to make sure that it is impossible to create a `Train` without creating the associated `Seat` instances, overwrite `save()`. Using a signal gives you a slightly less tight coupling, but I don't think it will give you any benefit here.

When overwriting `save()`, you can check if `self.pk` is `None` to see if a model is created or updated:

```
# models.py
class Train(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, *kwargs):
        created = self.pk is None
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if created:
            self.create_seats()
```

If you want to only create Seats when a Train is created through the admin, create a custom `ModelAdmin`:

```
class TrainAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        if not change:
            obj.create_seats()
```

Both examples assume your `Train` class has a `create_seats()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can override save method of your model or use a post_save signal on Train model.

First approach, overriding model save method:

```
class Train(models.Model):
    .
    .
    .

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        is_new = not self.pk

        # Call save method of super
        super(Train, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        # Add your seats here
```

Second approach, using a signal, write this to your models.py file:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Train)
def post_train_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # Add your seats here
```