# Where to put a code that interacts with DB and should run once on the project startup in django 2.2 or higher?

Tags: django

I'm trying to write some code that checks on something, if exists then cool and if not creates it.

The problem is, where to put this code? Django doesn't recommend putting anything that deals with DB at an app's `ready()` function - **this is what I'm currently doing but it gives me an error on debugging and give an error too on the beginning but works later on**-.

Also, what I have found seems outdated and a bit hacky like putting it at `urls.py` or `wsgi.py`.

I feel there must be a better way to do it.

Thank you all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define default data for Django Models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739439/how-to-define-default-data-for-django-models)

Answer (score 0):

Typically DB interactions within Django apps happen within the views.py file. I would suggest writing a view that uses the get_or_create model method.

Here is the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create